# Building a Boost.Python application on MacOS 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: c++, python, compilation, boost-python, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to Mavericks, and am now unable to build my application after much troubleshooting.

During linking, I receive the errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)
  .
  .
  .
 "boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id_aux(boost::python::type_info, std::pair<void*, boost::python::type_info> (*)(void*))"
```

I am using g++ from macports, specifically g++-mp-4.4.  Clang is not an option for my project, as my project depends upon OpenMP, which is currently incompatible with Clang.

I have not been using the C++11 runtime, but the Boost.Python library from macports (the one I am using during linking) is linked against it.

```
otool -L libboost_python-mt.dylib
libboost_python-mt.dylib:
    /opt/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Is this the root of my problem? Compiling part of my project with Clang succeeds (and hurdles this linking error stage), yet as I mentioned, I required OpenMP.

Notably, running:

```
nm  libboost_python-mt.dylib | c++filt | grep boost::python::objects::function_object
```

outputs

```
0000000000013d60 T boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&)
0000000000013d00 T boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)
```

which have std::__1 prefixes, which do not match what is expected in the undefined symbols errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was achieved by installing and linking against a version of Boost that was not compiled with c++11. The version of Boost provided by Macports apparently built Boost.Python with C++11, despite the fact that I specifically set the Macports compiler to be g++-mp-4.4, which should not be able to build with C++11...

Note that at the time of writing, it is quite difficult to install Boost libraries compiled with g++ via Macports, and I eventually installed Boost libraries from source.

Comment: how did you do that?  I'm having the same problem

Comment: download the Boost source and configure your build system to use the correct g++ version (the macports 4.4 and 4.6 versions worked for me), then build boost python following the standard Boost

Comment: Thanks I'm doing that now.  I don't totally understand what's wrong.  If boost is built with c++11, and so is my program, why are there linker errors?

Comment: Hi Neil, it may have to do with two different C++ runtimes on OS X (ugh).  You can specify --stdlib=c++ or --stdlib=libstdc++, and it's likely that your linker errors are because of different ones are being used for the libraries you are linking.