# Link error with boost-python installed by macports on Mavericks

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, macports, boost-python

I upgraded to maverics and now the macports version of boost-python doesn't work.

I installed ports: gcc48 and boost +python33.

I tried to compile this program with c++11 or without c++11:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
class A {};
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libblah) {
  boost::python::class_<A>("A");
}
```

I used cmake, but the build commands generated are below along with the linker error that I get:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cc.o
g++   -Da_EXPORTS -std=gnu++0x -save-temps=obj -arch x86_64 -fPIC -I/Users/neil/nn/src -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -F/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/mkspecs/macx-clang -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -I/Users/neil/nn/src/.    -o CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cc.o -c /Users/neil/nn/src/a.cc
Linking CXX shared module liba.so
g++   -std=gnu++0x -save-temps=obj -arch x86_64 -bundle -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   -o liba.so CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cc.o  -L/opt/local/lib  -L/Users/neil/nn/src /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/libpython3.3.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/neil/nn/src
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*>, mpl_::int_<0> >(void (*)(_object*), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector2<void, _object*> const&, std::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&, mpl_::int_<0>) in a.cc.o
  "boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id_aux(boost::python::type_info, std::pair<void*, boost::python::type_info> (*)(void*))", referenced from:
      void boost::python::objects::register_dynamic_id<A>(A*) in a.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

How can I work around this bug without installing boost by myself.  As with this [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134223/building-a-boost-python-application-on-macos-10-9-mavericks/20135600#comment32086701_20135600), the symbols in the library

```
nm  libboost_python-mt.dylib | c++filt | grep boost::python::objects::function_object
```

are found:

```
0000000000013d60 T boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&)
0000000000013d00 T boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)
```

However, they have std::__1 prefixes, which do not match what is expected in the undefined symbols errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the compiler to `clang++`, and that worked.  Would have preferred a better solution.